# Unable to factory reset Moto G

Tags: factory-reset, motorola-moto-g

I have a first prepaid gen Moto G that has stopped working. I've never done anything to this phone (no root, custom images or unlocked bootloader). When the phone boots up, as soon as I unlock the screen, I get one of the following messages:

`Unfortunately, Launcher has stopped
 Unfortunately, Google Play Service has stopped`

When I dismiss that the following messages start appearing,

`Unfortunately, Google Play Service has stopped
 Unfortunately, android.process.acore has stopped
 Unfortunately, android.process.media has stopped
 Unfortunately, android.process.gapps has stopped`

It is impossible to use the phone to change anything, and the homescreen image goes away quickly after I dismiss the first error message.

I've booted the phone in safe mode and the same thing happens.

I've tried doing a factory reset of the phone, but this does not work either. I can boot the phone into fastboot mode, but when I try to select the 'recovery' options I get a "boot up failed" message.

Here is all the info I can provide on the phone:

```
$ fastboot getvar all
(bootloader) version: 0.5
(bootloader) version-bootloader: 4113
(bootloader) product: falcon
(bootloader) secure: yes
(bootloader) hwrev: 0x83C0
(bootloader) radio: 0x3
(bootloader) emmc: 8GB Sandisk REV=06 PRV=07 TYPE=17
(bootloader) ram: 1024MB Samsung S4 SDRAM DIE=4Gb
(bootloader) cpu: MSM8626 CS
(bootloader) serialno: TA96504AK5
(bootloader) cid: 0x0002
(bootloader) channelid: 0x00
(bootloader) uid: 016D1F020F000000000000000000
(bootloader) unlocked: no
(bootloader) iswarrantyvoid: no
(bootloader) mot_sst: 0
(bootloader) max-download-size: 536870912
(bootloader) reason: Volume down key pressed
(bootloader) imei: 
(bootloader) meid: 
(bootloader) date: 
(bootloader) sku: 
(bootloader) iccid: 
(bootloader) cust_md5: 
(bootloader) max-sparse-size: 268435456
(bootloader) current-time: "Tue May  5  1:36:14 UTC 2015"
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[0]: motorola/falcon_verizon/falcon_cdm
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[1]: a:4.4.4/KXB21.14-L1.41/42:user/rel
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[2]: ease-keys
(bootloader) ro.build.version.full[0]: Blur_Version.210.12.41.falcon_cdm
(bootloader) ro.build.version.full[1]: a.Verizon.en.US
(bootloader) ro.build.version.qcom[0]: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1
(bootloader) ro.build.version.qcom[1]: .04.04.02.048.020
(bootloader) version-baseband: 
(bootloader) kernel.version[0]: Linux version 3.4.42-gaf6580c (hudsoncm@
(bootloader) kernel.version[1]: ilclbld54) (gcc version 4.7 (GCC) ) #1 S
(bootloader) kernel.version[2]: MP PREEMPT Wed Jun 25 01:50:02 CDT 2014
(bootloader) sdi.git: git=MBM-NG-V41.13-0-gdc5aeaf
(bootloader) sbl1.git: git=MBM-NG-V41.13-0-g683cb0c
(bootloader) rpm.git: git=MBM-NG-V41.13-0-g71b1aae
(bootloader) tz.git: git=MBM-NG-V41.13-0-ga27c415
(bootloader) aboot.git: git=MBM-NG-V41.13-0-g7dc8e78
(bootloader) qe: qe 0/1
(bootloader) ro.carrier: vzw
```

Since this is a verizon version, I can't unlock the bootloader.

Is there anything else I can try at this point? Or is this phone dead? All other posts I've seen for similar issues with "boot up failed" end up saying that Motorola said it was a hardware issue. However, this phone was working fine up until a week ago when I traveled to a new country.